# Why do the bosses in Metal Gear Rising speak via codec after killing them?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

For some reason, after killing the bosses they call via codec and speak. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the gem of Metal Gear.

In order to provide more of a narrative, The game pauses the action and zooms in on the two characters. This is possible by the fact that there are "nanomachines" that assist in the data transmission between the two actors. Metal Gear Solid 1 laid the framework for how this is possible, but the short answer is "genetically engineered nanomachines". Originally, the codec was a radio similar to short wave walkie-talkie's then as the story progressed, the codec becomes more and more advanced.

[Codec Wiki](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Radio)

Think of it like every other action movie, everyone has been shot multiple times, are bleeding out, but the action pauses so the hero can ask why and there's a long drawn-out reason for it. Hideo went with the same idea. So the bosses final words are usually the reasoning behind it.

Comment: We will forever miss the codec, it was first gutted in MGS4 and totally left behind afterwards, love that rising brought it back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy, I´ll mark it as the right one, but just something else I haven´t got clear; To sum up, is it like the nanomachines allow them to speak during some kind of "last breath"?

Comment: Yeah. The nanomachines would serve as the relay to enable the codec device in the small bones of the ear.

Comment: Cheers man! Good to know